# Bare React Native Up and Running (Expo), Expo-web-browser:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I was trying to follow Expo documentation to bare react native ([link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/bare/hello-world/)).

I am running on android emulator in Linux Manjaro.

After installing `expo init --template bare-minimum`, `react-native run-android` the emulator working fine.

However, after I ran `npm install expo-web-browser`, it gives this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-web-browser:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

```
$react-native info
info 
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 4.19 Manjaro Linux undefined
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
      Memory: 160.20 MB / 7.52 GB
      Shell: 5.0.11 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.11.1 - /usr/bin/node
      npm: 6.12.0 - /usr/bin/npm
    SDKs:
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 28, 29
        Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
        System Images: android-28 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.10 => 0.59.10 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Edited build.gradle's
`implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10"  // From node_modules`

Edit:

module, mostly give me `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` error. Possible didnt set up the environment correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

It was due to Android to Android X migration where the mapping have been changed. Such as 
`android.support.annotation.Nullable` to `androidx.annotation.Nullable`.

There are a number of them, I dont exactly remember all of them. But if you run them in Android Studio, you try to build it, it will tell you where and which line is the error, so you can just search them in [this link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings)